# Can i map through a list of components?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, components

[Subcomplist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABwMs.png) I am trying to build a customized carousel class for different components that have different props.

Some of the props don't exist in the respective components. Ill handle those situations with conditionals

I have a list of components I made and I want to map through them so that can display all at once where they need to be displayed

I made a component called "SubcompList" and inside of it I assigned a variable to the list of components.

Is this a legal action?

Comment: Can you post more information about the problem?

Comment: well, in the constructor for Subcomplist I'm calling all the props of every Component I made that I want the carousel function to be available in. that is also not working properly. The link to the picture might clear things up abit

Answer (score -1):

It's very common to map over an array to render a list of component, but it's commonly seen in cases where the array is the props that a component needs to render.

Something like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) in the react documentation